# Simplifying a query with correlated subquery to simple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in simplifying the below query.

I was able to check for '0' count without using Group By/having Count clauses in the below query but with correlated subquery.

Now, I've been asked to simplify the below query as simple joins!.

I tried merging the query into one. But the output differs.

Could you please suggest any other idea of simplifying the query, which is checking for '0' count.

```
select distinct tab1.col1
  from tab1
  where tab1.col2 = 'A'
  And 0 = (select count(tab2.col1)
            from tab2
            where tab2.col2 = 'B'
            and tab2.col1 = tab1.col1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing would normally be written as a NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT distinct tab1.col1
  FROM tab1
 WHERE tab1.col2 = 'A'
   AND NOT EXISTS( 
      SELECT 1
        FROM tab2
       WHERE tab2.col2 = 'B'
         AND tab2.col1 = tab1.col1 )
```

However you could also write

```
SELECT tab1.col1, count(tab2.col1)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE col2 = 'A') tab1,
       (SELECT * FROM tab2 WHERE col2 = 'B') tab2 
 WHERE tab1.col1 = tab2.col2(+)
 GROUP BY tab1.col1
HAVING count(tab2.col1) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try some of these.
If col1 is declared as not null, the first two queries have the same execution plan (anti-joins). The second alternative is my personal advice, since it matches your requirements the best.

```
-- Non-correlated subquery
select distinct col1
  from tab1
 where col2 = 'A'
   and col1 not in(select col1 
                     from tab2 
                    where col2 = 'B');

-- Correlated subquery
select distinct col1
  from tab1
 where col2 = 'A'
   and not exists(select 'x'
                    from tab2 
                   where tab2.col2 = 'B'
                     and tab2.col1 = tab1.col1);

-- Using join
select distinct tab1.col1
  from tab1 
  left join tab2 on(tab2.col2 = 'B' and tab2.col1 = tab1.col1)
 where tab1.col2 = 'A'
   and tab2.col1 is null;

-- Using aggregation   
select tab1.col1
  from tab1 
  left join tab2 on(tab2.col2 = 'B' and tab2.col1 = tab1.col1)
 where tab1.col2 = 'A'
 group 
    by tab1.col1
having count(tab2.col2) = 0;
```